# Will Ruby on Rails Gems Override My Models? - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Let's say that I created a custom scaffold (model, controller, views) for comments, but I decide after the fact that I want to use a gem such as "acts_as_commentable".

For example, I have comment.rb as a model and the gem creates this same model.

Will the Gem still work properly? I am assuming it will either fail or override. What should one do in a situation like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes, the gem will work fine with your comment model. If you look here: https://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable/blob/master/lib/comment_methods.rb you'll notice that acts_as_commentable is namespaced within its own module, and furthermore within its own Comment module.

Here's a good article about namespacing modules: http://dan.chak.org/enterprise-rails/chapter-3-organizing-with-modules/

Also, acts_as_commentable doesn't inherit from ActiveRecord::Base, so it looks like it should play nice with your app.

When in doubt, take a look at the source code ;)